# Moments of inertia of a torus

Tags: integration

So, I can show that the moment of inertia of a torus about its axis of symmetry is $I_z = 4\pi^2\rho r^5\left[ \frac{3a}{8b} + \frac{a^3}{2b^3}\right]$ where $a$ is the distance from the axis to the centre of the torus's circular cross section and $b$ is the radius of that circular cross section. I did this by doubling the integral for a semicircle revolved around the z-axis:
$$I_z = 2 \int_{a-b}^{a+b} x^2 \rho 2\pi x zdx$$
with $z = \sqrt{b^2 - (x-a)^2}$.

But I've been banging my head trying to set up the problem for the moment of inertia about the $x$ (or $y$) axis. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Yes - perhaps I should have said.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can find is to use a triple integral in cylindrical coordinates.  The torus has equation
$$(r-a)^2+z^2=b^2\ ,$$
and the square of the perpendicular distance from $(x,y,z)$ to the $x$-axis is $D^2=y^2+z^2$.  If the torus has density $\rho$ then
$$I_x=\int\!\!\int\!\!\int D^2\,dm
  =2\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\int_{a-b}^{a+b}\!\!\int_0^{\sqrt{b^2-(r-a)^2}}
    (r^2\sin^2\theta+z^2)\,\rho\,r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta\ .$$
Doing the integration is a bit of a pain, involving powers of trig functions, but the techniques are "standard".

Comment: I think I get it - the expression in () is x^2? Thanks, David.

Comment: The expression in brackets is $y^2+z^2$, which is the square of the distance from $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,0,0)$.

Comment: could you make a general formula for all components of the inertia tensor for the main axes?